# JQuery images in plone4

Tags: jquery, image, plone

Which product for Plone 4 can I use to insert preview-sized images in sites and so on, and have them automatically jquery-linked to their fullsize views? Eg: as it's been solved in the plone.org products screenshot preview.

Answer (score 4):

plone.app.jquerytools is included in Plone 4, and may be added to Plone 3.3.x. See the [documentation on the overlay helpers](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.jquerytools/1.2b4#overlay-helpers) for recipes for setting up popups for images. It is the popup manager for Plone 4, and is what we're using on Plone.Org.

Answer (score 2):

Try [collective.prettyphoto](http://plone.org/products/collective.prettyphoto). Works for me on several sites.